# Checking if File is open to prevent error

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have looked and could not find an answer to this specifically. The below code prompts the user as to whether or not a specific file is open. If the user clicks no, the sub ends. If they click yes, the sub continues. I have tested this with the file open and all works great. But then I forgot to open the file and clicked yes when prompted and received the following error:

Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range

For this line in the code:

With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - December 2015.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")

I understand why I am getting the error, but how do I check if the "yes" answer from the user is true to prevent this error?

Here is the full code:

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1512_December()
'
'
    Dim ANS As String
    ANS = MsgBox("Is the December 2015 Swivel Master File checked out of SharePoint and currently open on this desktop?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Master File Open")
    If ANS = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "This procedure will now terminate.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Terminate Procedure"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' This line renames the worksheet to "Extract"
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Extract"

    ' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

    ' This unhides any hidden rows
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Dim LR As Long

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "12" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next LR

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("D2:D2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("O2:O2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("J2:J2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("K2:K2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("L2:L2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:Z2000")
    .Apply
End With
Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select

    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "12" Then

            ' As opposed to selecting the cells, this will copy them directly
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Copy

            ' As opposed to "Activating" the workbook, and selecting the sheet, this will paste the cells directly
            With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - December 2015.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")
                erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have worked through many errors in this code over the last two days and am a little fried, so any help is appreciated.

Here is my updated IF statement to check the status of the workbook required to proceed:

```
Dim ANS As String

    ANS = MsgBox("Is the November 2015 Swivel Master File checked out of SharePoint and currently open on this desktop?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Master File Open")
    If ANS = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "This procedure will now terminate.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Terminate Procedure"
        Exit Sub
        ElseIf IsWBOpen("Swivel - Master - November 2015") Then
    End If
```

Comment: Hmm your if test above should work. Why leave it to user though? Open it via code.

Comment: All of that does work if the file is actually open. I get the error when the file is not open and the user clicks yes. Then when the macro continues and tries to copy data to the file, that is when I get the error. I have also done research on how to check out and open a file from SharePoint, but I cannot get it to work for me. I am thinking this has to do with internal security, but have not verified that yet. So that is why I am going the MsgBox route.

Comment: Ah sharepoint. Run a loop like `for each bk in application.workbooks | if bk.name = Swivel - Master - December 2015.xlsm then flag="open" else flag="not open"` then later do a test on `flag` and do `exit sub` if flag=not open. Makes sense? Edit: `bk.name` might give whole path so check accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks findwindow. I will try this and let you know if it does all that I need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to check if the desired workbook is open:

```
Function IsWBOpen(WorkbookName As String) As Boolean
' check if WorkbookName is already opened; WorkbookName is without path or extension!
' comparison is case insensitive
' 2015-12-30

    Dim wb As Variant
    Dim name As String, searchfor As String
    Dim pos as Integer

    searchfor = LCase(WorkbookName)
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        pos = InStrRev(wb.name, ".")
        If pos = 0 Then                           ' new wb, no extension
            name = LCase(wb.name)
        Else
            name = LCase(Left(wb.name, pos - 1))  ' strip extension
        End If
        If name = searchfor Then
            IsWBOpen = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wb
    IsWBOpen = False
End Function
```

It looks through the list of (opened) workbooks and compares the name to it's argument. The extension is stripped off, there is no path prepended and the comparison is case-insensitive.
Usage:
`If IsWbOpen("Swivel - Master - December 2015") then
'... proceed
Else
    Exit Sub
End If`

Comment: So I am clear in understanding (still fairly new to VBA and learning rapidly thanks to SO), I do not name the workbook in the function, just in the If statement? If that is true, then I can use that If statement in other similar subs where the workbook name is slightly different (like 'Swivel - Master - November 2015')? So here is a silly question, does a function need to be in it's own module?

Comment: Your first assumption is 100% correct, by using a parameter to that function you can use it universally. Second, well, the function needs to be in a module but not necessarily in it's own. If you put it into a module in your PERSONL.XLS you could use it from any workbook.

Comment: Small glitch (I am sure it is user error (user=me)). I edited the original question above to show the IF statement I am using with the function you provided. I made no change to the function statement. But when I run the code, I get the following error if the workbook is not open and the user clicks Yes: Run-time error '5':  Invalid procedure call or argument. And the debugger points to this line in the function: name = LCase(Left(wb.name, InStrRev(wb.name, ".") - 1))  ' strip extension. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. If a workbook has never been saved it's name will not include an extension, hence no dot. I've included an additional test in my post.

Comment: Ok. Changed the function according to your edit. Now I am getting a **Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range** for 'With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - November 2015.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")' Keep in mind that I am clicking Yes, but the workbook is NOT open. The desired result should be the MsgBox stating that this procedure will now terminate, the same as if the user clicks No. So, I believe your function and If statements are working fine, but mine seem to be the issue. I also think I have been looking at this too long. %}

Comment: That's expected behavior if the WB is not open at that time, the subscript being "Swivel - ...". I'd write `ElseIf not IsWBOpen then exit sub` to catch a false positive user input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99327/discussion-between-iron-man-and-user1016274).